# Table creation derby sql jpa

Tags: sql, jpa, derby

Hi guys i am looking for a bit of help

i have got

```
create table usertable (
        username varchar(128) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT USER_PK PRIMARY KEY ,
        password varchar(128) NOT NULL
);


create table grouptable(
        username varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        groupid  varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT GROUP_PK PRIMARY KEY(username, groupid),
        CONSTRAINT USER_FK FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES usertable(username)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    );
```

to have a username and password to be stored into the database, what i am asking is how can i add another table called address and link it with the usertable in a many-to-one realtionship as one user could have several address, how do i go about doing this ?

Thanks guys !

EDIT

would this work ?

```
create table usertable (
        username varchar(128) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT USER_PK PRIMARY KEY ,
        password varchar(128) NOT NULL,
firstaname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
surname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
gender varchar(6) NOT NULL,
homenumber varchar(128) NOT NULL,
mobilenumber varchar(128) NOT NULL,
dob date NOT NULL,
id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)
);


create table grouptable(
        username varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        groupid  varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT GROUP_PK PRIMARY KEY(username, groupid),
        CONSTRAINT USER_FK FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES usertable(username)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    );

create table address(
username varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                addressline1 varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                addressline2 varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                addressline3 varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                country varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                postcode varchar(9) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT USER2_FK FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES usertable(username)
                     );
```

EDIT 2 :

```
create table usertable (
        username varchar(128) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT USER_PK PRIMARY KEY,
        password varchar(128) NOT NULL,
firstaname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
surname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
gender varchar(6) NOT NULL,
homenumber varchar(128) NOT NULL,
mobilenumber varchar(128) NOT NULL,
dob date NOT NULL,
id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)
);


create table grouptable(
        username varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        groupid  varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT GROUP_PK PRIMARY KEY(username, groupid),
        CONSTRAINT USER_FK FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES usertable(username)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    );

create table address(
ID NUMERIC(3) not null primary key,
                 username varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                addressline1 varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                addressline2 varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                addressline3 varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                country varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                postcode varchar(9) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT USER2_FK FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES usertable(username)
                     );
```

Comment: Create an address table containing a username column, which is a foreign key to usertable.username.

Comment: would the above work ?

Comment: You didn't define any primar key for the address table. It should have an ID column which is its PK. I don't see why the username in grouptable is in the PK. The group id should be sufficient to uniquely identify a group. Other than that, yes, it's OK. You should read an introductory book or tutorial about relational database design, because you need to understand that before using Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, would it be possible for you to show me the correct layout for my tables ? and also do you have any recommendations on a good tutorial ?